# Problem with citation (authoryear) in NJDwileyV5 template?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, wiley-article

I came across the `NJDwileyV5` Latex template and when I try to use `\citet{}` for citation, i.e. author, (year), in the text the result is always just a number as if it a footnote number with no author no years. I tried all provided packages for the bibliography with the `NJDwileyV5.cls`. Here is the body of the article:

```
\documentclass[AMA,Times1COL]{WileyNJDv5} %STIX1COL,STIX2COL,STIXSMALL

\articletype{Article Type}%

\received{Date Month Year}
\revised{Date Month Year}
\accepted{Date Month Year}
\journal{Journal}
\volume{00}
\copyyear{2023}
\startpage{1}

\raggedbottom

\bibliographystyle{wileyNJD-Harvard}

\begin{document}
```

.

**\citet{Hirt1974}**

[image]